# How to pass date values from dataframe to query in Spark /Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading the data from Store table which is in snowflake. I want to pass the date from dataframe maxdatefromtbl to my query in spark sql to filter records.
This condition (s"CREATED_DATE!='$maxdatefromtbl'") is not working as expected

```
var retail = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(options).option("query","Select MAX(CREATED_DATE) as CREATED_DATE  from RSTORE").load()
val maxdatefromtbl =  retail.select("CREATED_DATE").toString

var retailnew = spark.read.format("snowflake").options(options).option("query","Select *  from RSTORE").load()

var finaldataresult = retailnew.filter(s"CREATED_DATE!='$maxdatefromtbl'")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select a single value from the `retail` dataframe to use in the filter.

```
val maxdatefromtbl = retail.select("CREATED_DATE").collect().head.getString(0)
var finaldataresult = retailnew.filter(col("CREATED_DATE") =!= maxdatefromtbl)
```

The type of `retail.select("CREATED_DATE")` is `DataFrame`, and `DataFrame.toString` returns the schema rather than the value of the single row you have. Please see the following example from a [Spark shell](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell).

```
scala> val s = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF()
scala> s.select("value").toString
res0: String = [value: int]
```

In first line in the code snipped above, `collect()` wraps the dataframe, with a single row in your case, in an array; `head` takes the first element of the array, and `.getString(0)` gets the value from the cell with at the index `0` as `String`. Please see the [DataFrame](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html) and [Row](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Row.html) documentation pages for more information.